# Storing data in a dynamodb

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I need to store varying keys of data in a dynamodb table. I am using node.js / aws lambda / dynamodb.

The information I am trying to store would look something like this:

```
[
 {
  "boxname":"foo",
  "contents": [
   {
    "itemid":"1",
    "itemname":"apple",
    "itemamount":"7",
    "itemdateadded":"03-17-2019"    
   }
  ]
  "boxname":"bar",
  "contents": [
   {
    "itemid":"1",
    "itemname":"apple",
    "itemamount":"2",
    "itemdateadded":"03-16-2019"
   }
   {
    "itemid":"2",
    "itemname":"orange",
    "itemamount":"1",
    "itemdateadded":"03-17-2019"
   }
  ]
 }
]
```

basically so I can query later, and add and remove each item from each box... I am having a lot of trouble wrapping my head around how to do this! Can anyone help?

Comment: There are a lot examples in AWS document, read it and get started. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html

Answer (score 1):

**DynamoDB Table**

Firstly, you will need to create a DynamoDB `Table`. To do so you will need to minimally have a table `Hash Key` which acts as the table's Primary Key, you can also have an optional `Range Key` which acts as the table's Composite Primary Key

From your sample data, `boxname` appears to fit well as the table `Hash Key`

You can go ahead to create a DynamoDB `Table` immediately with only the Hash Key, as all the other attributes do not need to be provided upfront, new / additional attributes can be added on the fly when creating new records

**Create Record**

You can use the `PutItem` API To create a record into DynamoDB

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_PutItem.html

**Query Records**

You can use the `Query` API to query records by the table's Hash Key, and optionally also the Range Key

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html

**Scan Records**

Use the `Scan` API to scan records by any `Non Key` attributes when you are unable to fetch records based on the table's `Hash Key` and / or `Range Key`

It is generally not recommended to create a Table structure that heavily uses the Scan API as it literally performs a Scan operation. Instead structuring your table optimised for Query operations is recommended

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Scan.html

**Get Record**

You can use the `GetItem` API to get a single record by the table's Hash Key, and optionally also the Range Key

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_GetItem.html

Hope the above information is good to get you started with DynamoDB

Answer (score 0):

While `boxname` is unique I strongly disagree it's a good fit for a hash key (as per @OhChinBoon's answer).

Since `boxname` is only a name, it means it's not uniformly generated (like an UUID). Imagine your `boxname`s were like `Johan/Johanan/Johann/Johannes/Johdy/John`. DynamoDB would struggle quite heavily to query on these keys given your table grows big.

I suggest you add a new attribute to your structure which will be responsible for being your hash key. Let's call it `id`.

Now, if you need to query for `boxname`, you could simply create a [Global Secondary Index](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.html) (GSI) on it, thus avoiding high cost operations like Scan (check [DynamoDB Best Practices](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/best-practices.html) if needed). Only use Scan as a last resort.

Based on the above, your structure would then look like this:

```
{
    "id": "7ba6d8b8-afef-440e-98a2-fee38a4e3381" (hash key)
    "boxname": "foo" (GSI),
    "contents": [{
        "itemid": "1",
        "itemname": "apple",
        "itemamount": "7",
        "itemdateadded": "03-17-2019"
    }]
}
```

Keep in mind that you can only create GSIs on top level attributes, meaning you cannot create a GSI for an attribute inside a JSON/Array. So, if you eventually need to query for something inside `contents`, then DynamoDB may not be a good fit (although I don't think this is your case, I think it's worth mentioning)